# API request translation from other lunguages to Python

Tags: python

I'm very new to **requests** and normally "developer guides" on API services include a Python section, but I've run into a case where Python was not one of their options. They included PHP, Java, and C#. My question is, how can I rebuild their API instructions to fit Python requests. Here are their examples:

> PHP

```
<?php
   $username = 'USERNAME';
   $password = 'PASSWORD';
   $FIM_endpoint = 'https://fim.api.ENV.fleetmatics.com/token';

   //Call method and set variable to authorization string
   $token = get_token($FIM_endpoint, $username, $password);

   echo $token;

   function get_token($url, $username, $password)
   {
      //Create necessary headers for REST call
      $headers = array();
      $headers[] = make_authorization_header($username, $password);    //Send to function to Base64 encode
      $headers[] = 'Accept: text/plain';                               //Authorization token comes back as plain text
   
      $session = curl_init($url);                             //Initialize transfer with URL
      curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);           //Exclude header info in response
      curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);    //Return transfer as a string of the return value of curl_exec()
      curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);    //Pass in headers
    
      //Execute transfer of $session
      $response = curl_exec($session); 

      //Get http code outcome of the #session transfer    
      $http_code = curl_getinfo($session, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

      //Measure false response/error          
      if($response === false)
      {
         echo 'Error: '. curl_error($session);
      }
      
      //ALWAYS close transfer connection        
      curl_close($session);

      //Evaluate variable for non 200(OK) http code       
      if($http_code !== 200)
      {
         echo 'Error: Http Status Code returned '.$http_code;
      }    
   
      return $response;    
   }
   
   function make_authorization_header($username, $password)
   {
      //Base64 encode username:password; note: the ':' must be present between them   
      $encodedString = base64_encode($username.':'.$password);
      
      //Return concatenated Authorization string      
      return 'Authorization: Basic '.$encodedString;
   }
?>
```

> Java

```
public class Program{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    
    // Set local variables
    String username = "username";
    String password = "password";
    String getTokenUri = "https://fim.api.ENV.fleetmatics.com/token";

    // Pass variables to create a new TokenGenerator object    
    TokenGenerator token = new TokenGenerator(username, password, getTokenUri);
    
    // Display auth string      
    System.out.println(token.GetAuthString());
  }
}
```

> C#

```
using System; // Note: This can be omitted if Console.WriteLine is not used

namespace Rest_Token_Example
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            // Set local variables 
            string username = "username";
            string password = "password";
            string getTokenURI = "https://fim.api.ENV.fleetmatics.com/token";

            // Pass variables to create a new TokenGenerator object
            var token = new TokenGenerator(username, password, getTokenURI);

            // Display token string
            Console.WriteLine(token.AuthString);
        }
    }
}
```

> My attempt in Python

```
authUser = "username"
authPass = "password"
authoURL = "https://fim.api.ENV.fleetmatics.com/tokens"

response = requests.get(authoURL, headers={authUser, authPass})

print (response)
#<Response [404]>
```

I have also tried replacing "headers" with "auth" in several formats, to no avail

Any help is appreciated greatly.

Comment: Where is `TokenGenerator` coming from (especially for Java)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the `php` code, I would try something like this. Note this follows the php fairly closely and it might be full of bugs as I can' really test it.

```py
import requests
import base64

def make_authorization_header(username, password):
    # Base64 encode username:password; note: the ':' must be present between them   
    encodedString = str(base64.b64encode(f"{username}:{password}".encode()))
      
    # Return concatenated Authorization string      
    return f'Authorization: Basic {encodedString}'


def get_token(url, username, password):
    # Create necessary headers for REST call
    headers = [
        make_authorization_header(username, password),  #Send to function to Base64 encode
        "Accept: text/plain"                            #Authorization token comes back as plain text
    ]

    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

    if not response.ok:
        print("Error...")
        return None

    return response.json()

username = "username"
password = "password"
FIM_endpoint  = "https://fim.api.ENV.fleetmatics.com/tokens"
token = get_token(FIM_endpoint, username, password)
print(token)
```

Comment: It appears that this worked with some tweaking, but I'm having trouble confirming as I'm having auth issues on my end. Waiting on customer support for that. I do want to note that the headers had to be passed as a dictionary: {"Authorization":authInfo, etc.}.

Comment: Definitely worked. Thank you.